# Import 50+ .dat files into SPSS using a loop

Tags: foreach, stata, spss

I need to import multiple .dat files (one for each state of the USA for several years) into SPSS and then save each file as a Stata .dta dataset. The files have standardized names with the year and state abbreviation, e.g. data_2000_AL.dat. I have SPSS code to read and format each file where, one by one, you specify the path for each state-year file and then run the code.

In Stata, I would save time by setting up `forvalues`/`foreach` loops to run through each year and state, i.e.:

```
forvalues y=2000/2010 {
    foreach s in AL AK AZ AR CA ... {
        [CODE TO RUN STATA .DCT FILES THAT READ/FORMAT .DAT FILES]
        save data_`y'_`s'.dta, replace
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I only have SPSS code (not Stata dictionary files), and I'm not familiar with SPSS. Is there a way to replicate the above Stata code in SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a macro to do this or Python. Here is a brief illustration on how to do it using a macro.

```
DEFINE !StateLoop (!POSITIONAL = !CMDEND) 
!DO !I !IN (!1) 
  !DO !J = 2000 !TO 2002 
    !LET !F = !QUOTE(!CONCAT(!I,"_",!J,".dat")) 
    ECHO !F. 
    *You import/export commands here.
  !DOEND 
!DOEND 
!ENDDEFINE. 

!StateLoop PA NY NJ.
```

This subsequently prints out:

```
PA_2000.dat 
PA_2001.dat 
PA_2002.dat 
NY_2000.dat 
NY_2001.dat 
NY_2002.dat 
NJ_2000.dat 
NJ_2001.dat 
NJ_2002.dat
```

It is just using the macro operators `!CONCAT` to make the strings necessary for each state and looping over them.

If you rather do this in python you can use `spss.Submit` and string substitution in a similar fashion:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM Python.
import spss
sa = ["PA","NY","NJ"]
for i in range(2):
  for j in sa:
    f = j + "_" + str(2000 + i)
    spss.Submit("""
                ECHO "%s".
                """ % (f))
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: The code to read in the data will either be `GET TRANSLATE` or `DATA LIST` (you can use data list with .dat files because they are plain text). To save to Stata would be `SAVE TRANSLATE`. Stata must surely be able to read in the .dat files directly though?

Comment: Perhaps like @Andy W I am confused on what the question is. It seems that you have Stata code and can read in .dat files and export Stata .dta files. Why then do you need to do in SPSS?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have Stata code. I was just trying to explain what I need to do in SPSS by using Stata code as an illustration (I am a Stata user). Andy W -- Stata can read .dat files if you have a corresponding dictionary file (.dct), but I sadly don't have that. I just have the SPSS code to read in the files one at a time, where at the beginning you specify the file path of the file you'd like to read in (e.g. "D:\DATA\data_2000_AL.DAT"). So I'd have to fill in the path for the Alabama file, then run and save, then fill in the path for the Arizona file, then run and save, etc. Thanks!